# How to add template Python files in package without compiling them?

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I'm trying to create Python package with the following structure:

```
project/
|-- project/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- templates/
|   |   |-- somefile.py
|-- setup.py
```

`somefile.py` is just a template file that is not syntactically correct.

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="...",
      version="1.1",
      ...
      packages=find_packages(),
      package_data={
          'project': 'templates/*',
      })
```

This works great for non-Python template files. But with the .py files, `setuptools` tries to compile `somefile.py`, which results in a Syntax error since the file is on purpose not syntactically correct. So, how can I add the template Python files in my package without compiling them?

Comment: Can you rename it to `somefile.template`? Then the code that applies the template will create a valid Python file.

Comment: For now that is what I do but I was hoping to find another solution.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the use case of the templates? Python is very dynamic and rarely needs code templates.

Comment: @KlausD. The point is to create starter files for python projects (I'm using jinja2 for templating).